# Roll a list in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a vector t with a size of 1 * n

```
t = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

I know the roll function can rotate vector for me but
is there anyway to have a list of k * n 
for example if k is 3, I need

```
t = [['a','b','c','d','e','f'],['f','a','b','c','d','e'],['e','f','a','b','c','d']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, couldn't find a vectorized way of tackling this. So I had to fall back to a for loop.

```
t = tf.constant(['a','b','c','d','e','f'], dtype=tf.string)
k = 3

new_t = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(tf.tile(t, [k]),[k,-1]))

rolled = [] 
for i in range(0,k):
  rolled.append(tf.roll(new_t[i], shift=i, axis=0))
rolled = tf.stack(rolled)
```